# how to authentificate user with salt passeword sha-1 with tomcat 7

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat7, jdbcrealm, saltedhash

I try to configure datasourceRealm using tomcat 7.0.x with user authentification data store in DataBase in two columns one with salt and another with hash. I don't know how to configure DataSourceRealm with password column and how to authentificate user. I'm newbie sorry if the question seems a little bit confuse. the things i would like to authentificate user with this existing DB. thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported out of the box. You'll need to implement a custom Realm for that.

Comment: i read that i've to override method authentificate in DataSourceRealm to implement this. That's for the theory. i would like to know if somebody succeed and if he can let me know, the differents steps to implement this. thanks in advance.

Comment: i'd succeed to write my own realm, if people are interesting to have sources i will post it as soon as i will have much more time. thanks.